# How do i read a JSON sent by ajax in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I am sending a JS array to my rails app :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/backend/familles/change_order.js",
        contentType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(sort_array)
      });
```

Here is how firefox see the ajax POST :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wdy2MJa.png]

But a params.inspect only contain the following :

```
{"controller"=>"backend/familles", "action"=>"change_order", "locale"=>"fr"}
```

What should I change to be able to read the JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly stringify your data object, jQuery will do that for you! Also you should add a key value for the data you wish to send. Something like this should work:

```
data: {"sort_array": sort_array}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
dataType: 'json'
```

not `contentType`

EDIT:

I think you should not send an Array directly. Try:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"items":sort_array})
```

or

```
data: {"items": JSON.stringify(sort_array)}
```

Comment: I did that but it still does not work. I also added contentType: 'application/json'

Comment: See my edit. I think that array should have a 'name'

Comment: I can now parse a string that give me the JSON data. However, i must remove the datatype, because if defined, the js view returned by the server is not interpreted. (some JS code).